# Using chmod for giving access to users

Tags: unix, chmod

I need to provide access to a file in UNIX to particular users.
How do i use chmod to do this?

Comment: what kind of access? http://catcode.com/teachmod/

Answer (score 2):

```
addgroup yourgroup
chgrp yourgroup filename
chmod g+w filename
adduser user1 yourgroup
adduser user2 yourgroup
```